# Is there any way to calculate $\binom{10}{1}-\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{5}-\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{9}$ faster?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers

During solving a problem I get this expression:

$$\binom{10}{1}-\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{5}-\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{9}$$

To calculate it normally, I do this way:

$$\binom{10}{1}-\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{5}-\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{9}=2\binom{10}{1}-2\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{5}$$
And here we have to evaluate $\binom{10}{3}$ and $\binom{10}{5}$. after all I got $32$ as the result correctly.

My question: Is there any other way to calculate this expression easier (faster)? I suspect there is because the answer is $32=2^5$ and I guess maybe there is other way to calculate it for example by combinations or other ways.

Comment: Yes. Consider $(1+i)^{10}$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang $(1+i)^{10}=(2i)^{5}=-32i$

Comment: It's positive 32i. Now take its binomial expansion and take the imaginary part

Comment: Oops. yes it is positive $32i$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang very nice. got it thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(1+i)^{10} = {10\choose 0} + {10\choose 1}i -{10\choose 2}-{10\choose 3}i +{10\choose 4}+ ... -{10\choose 10} $$

$$(1-i)^{10} = {10\choose 0} - {10\choose 1}i -{10\choose 2}+{10\choose 3}i +{10\choose 4}+...-{10\choose 10}$$

So $$...={(1+i)^{10}-(1-i)^{10}\over 2i} = {1\over 2i}((2i)^5-(-2i)^5) = 32$$

Comment: It would be better if you write the last term of each expansion

Comment: @Aqua , As BenjaminWang mentioned in comments wouldn't $(1+i)^{10}$ suffice to conclude the expression is equal to $32$?

Comment: He mentioned imaginary part of it, that is what I calculated. $$Im(z) = {z-\overline{z}\over 2i}$$

Comment: Hmm. got it. nice trick!

Comment: For me, it would be easier to evaluate the sum directly in this case as the numbers are small, sure if the numbers are bigger, this method is preferable.